# VPN - Unique client certificates?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Currently installing the OpenVPN service on my Linux box and stumbled across this in a guide:

> All of our clients will also need certificates to be able to
>   authenticate. These keys and certificates will be shared with your
>   clients, and it's best to generate separate keys and certificates for
>   each client you intend on connecting.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7

May somebody please explain why it's important to generate a pair for each client? Are there security risks if, for example, 2 clients use the same pair? As far as I can remember, my school and workplace does offer one pair for all users if they want to use the VPN service.

Comment: It's just in case someone leaves the organisation. You can revoke their certificate, rather than have to reissue everyone else a new cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can authenticate based on certificate, username/password or by using a combination.

The reason why you do not want to use just a single certificate, without username or password, is that it will reduce your accountability as you can't pinpoint a single connection to a single person with certainty. You can use username and password as a measure to resolve this issue.

It's better  to implement a certificate per client as well as username/password. It will give you a form of 2 factor authentication setup (its effectiveness is debatable if stored on the same computer).

- Something the client has: his certificate
- Something the client knows: username and password